# is there any way to request to server with fake server time?

Tags: http, request

When I request to web server with http request, the server send the response with headers. I want to change the server time ; actually the respose header's Date value. Is it possible to change or fake the time of web server? because I want to know the answer in time advance.

Comment: there are three simple answers to this. 1. if you have access to your server, then log on and set its time in the future or 2. much more simply, when you grab the server time in your code, add time to it to make it in the future before using it, 3. set your client to be in the past. Or if you're just looking for a delay, add a pause in the script on the server

Comment: thanks your answer. for 2. how can i use the time with http request? are there any sample code available?

Comment: what coding language?

Comment: java is good to me. any other language is OK ! thanks in advance, Christian.

Comment: javascript is good to me.